# Regular expression for @ after space in text area

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, regex

Write a regular expression for @ in some text, but @ must be after space only...
Please help me...
In this case am using [AT JS](http://ichord.github.io/At.js/)
Actually am problem is i need to make ajax call after @,followed by space as in the following scenario [Screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbc13.png)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#editable').bind("keyup", function(event){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'index.php/tags',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result)
        {
            jQuery('#editable').atwho({
                at: "@",
                data: result,
                limit: 50,
                minLen:1,
                callback: {
                    filter: function (query, data, search_key) {
                        return jQuery.map(data, function(item, i) {
                            return item[search_key].toLowerCase().indexOf(query) < 0 ? null : item
                        })
                    }

                }
            });
        },
    });
});
```

});

Comment: Like `/ @/`?   ...

Comment: Where exactly do you intend to use the RegExp? Its not clear what you want to do. Also check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not so clear what your asking but...

`const regex = /\s@\w+\s/g`

This will find all the times that you have in a string a space, followed by an @, followed by one or more alphanumeric characters followed by a space.

Comment: Ya, I want  like this regular expression. @ followed by a space in text

Comment: than you would just do
        const regex = /@\s/g
will find all @ signs but only if followed by a space

Answer (score 0):

In addition to whats been answered, u can add an extra + to \s

```
+ means 1 or more, but atleastone space.
* means 0 or more
```

So, u could do these:-

```
const regex = /\s+@\w+\s+/g; // one or more spaces, but atleastone space.
const regex = /\s*@\w+\s*/g; // 0 or more spaces
```

Other than that, the above answered is correct if u r looking for just one "hardcoded" space; which may become a problem, in case ur input has more spaces.